# IBM MF8 Adapter Mashup - POST Requests

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, apache-httpcomponents

I tried a sample for post requests in IBM MF8 Java adapter.

Inside this adapter, I am trying to to call another Java adapter, SampleAdapter and want to do a POST with userDetails as parameter

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/balanced")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = false)
public JSONObject generate(UserDetails userDetails , HttpRequest request,  HttpSession session) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String messages = null;

    String getProcedureURL = "/SampleAdapter/resource";
    StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(userDetails.toString(),ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getProcedureURL);
    httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    HttpResponse response;
    try {

        response = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(httpPost);
        jsonObj = adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(response);
        messages = (String)jsonObj.get("subscriptionMessage");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("value", messages);

    return json;
}
```

SampleAdapter has to get the object userDetails. So that I can use it in the back end for some operations.

But, here I am unable to get the data into SampleAdapter. Also, I tried returning some String from SampleAdapter.

I get the below error

```
{"responseText":"","error":"Response cannot be parsed to JSON"}
```

I know that IBM MF does the json conversion internally, but here how is it possible to do a POST from one adapter to adapter. 
I see samples given only for GET requests.
Any suggestions to do for POST?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote you a short example based on yours:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/balanced")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = false)
public JSONObject generate() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String messages = null;

    String getProcedureURL = "/SampleAdapter/resource/hello";
    StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity("world", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getProcedureURL);
    httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    HttpResponse response;
    try {

        response = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(httpPost);
        jsonObj = adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(response);
        messages = "Hello " + (String)jsonObj.get("name");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("value", messages);

    return json;
}
```

And here is the POST endpoint:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/hello")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = false)
public Map<String, String> hello(String name) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    result.put("name", name);
    return result;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for code. But, my issue is with passing the whole object to the other adapter.
I want to know if there is an option to pass "userDetails" (request) to the other adapter.

Comment: Can you please add to the question the SampleAdapter resource endpoint and a description of the userDetails object?